# How do I find the definition of a named constraint in Oracle?

Tags: oracle

All I know about the constraint is it's name (`SYS_C003415`), but I want to see it's definition.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Another option would be to reverse engineer the DDL...

```
DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL('CONSTRAINT', 'SYS_C003415')
```

Some examples here....

http://www.psoug.org/reference/dbms_metadata.html

Comment: If it's a Foreign Key Constraint, you have to put "REF_CONSTRAINT" instead: `select DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL('REF_CONSTRAINT', 'SYS_C003415') from dual`

Answer (score 36):

Looks like I should be querying `ALL_CONSTRAINTS`.

```
select OWNER, CONSTRAINT_NAME, CONSTRAINT_TYPE, TABLE_NAME, SEARCH_CONDITION from ALL_CONSTRAINTS where CONSTRAINT_NAME = 'SYS_C003415';
```

Answer (score 8):

Use following query to get a definition of constraint in oracle:

```
Select DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL('CONSTRAINT', 'CONSTRAINT_NAME') from dual
```

Comment: If someone wanna kown what excatly do the constraint, you must to run it, thanks @Rakesh Girase

Comment: To avoid any confusion, note that `CONSTRAINT_NAME` is supposed to be replaced with the name of your constraint. `CONSTRAINT` should be kept as it is.

Answer (score 0):

Or to see all constaints use SYS.DBA_CONSTRAINTS  (If you have the privileges)